# Deleting a row that was just added to the last row of a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete a row that was just added to the last row of a table. It may seem pointless but it is to update a table of info to trigger a series of updates to figures for a project.

I tried a few different ways but every time the `.delete` method doesn't work. I'm not sure if I'm using it with the right objects. I replaced the `.delete` with `.add` to see what happens and it works (now adds two rows).

```
Option Explicit

Sub update_chart()

'------------------------ Setup-----------------------------------
Dim s1_sheet As Worksheet
Dim s1_table_list_object As ListObject
Dim s1_table_object_row As ListRow
Dim s1_last_row_with_data As Long
Dim s1_sheet_m As Worksheet
Dim s1_table_list_object_m As ListObject
Dim s1_table_object_row_m As ListRow
Dim s1_last_row_with_data_m As Long

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set s1_sheet = Sheets("Semester 1 Datalog") 'The sheet that the table is on
Set s1_table_list_object = s1_sheet.ListObjects(1)
Set s1_table_object_row = s1_table_list_object.ListRows.Add
Set s1_sheet_m = Sheets("Semester 1 Datalog") 'The sheet that the table is on
Set s1_table_list_object_m = s1_sheet_m.ListObjects(1)
Set s1_table_object_row_m = s1_table_list_object_m.ListRows.Delete 

'---------------------------- Semester 1 ----------------------------------
If (Worksheets("Backend_2").Cells(4, "K") = "1") Then
    s1_table_object_row.Range(1, "A").Value2 = Worksheets("GUI").Cells(13, "P")
    s1_last_row_with_data = s1_sheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    s1_table_object_row_m.Range(1, "A").Value2 = Worksheets("GUI").Cells(13, "P") ' need to fix
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Which row are you trying to delete - `s1_table_object_row`?

Comment: i am trying to delete the row that was added at the bottom of the table, which is the one that you listed. The variable to delete it is s1_table_object_row_m

Comment: I'm not sure you need a new variable: `s1_table_object_row.Delete`?

Comment: what do you mean? you think i could just use the same variable as the .add but use .delete?

Comment: Basically, yes. `ListRows.Add` returns a new list row, so you have `Set s1_table_object_row = s1_table_list_object.ListRows.Add`. To delete that list row, all you need to do is `s1_table_object_row.Delete` - no `Set`, no new variable. See the [`ListRow.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrow.delete) documentation.

Comment: Ok so i dont need another set of variables to do this. Why when i switch the .delete to .add it works but doesnt work with .delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different methods here:

---

> [`ListRows.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrows.add): Adds a new row to the table represented by the specified `ListObject`.
>
> **Return Value**: A `ListRow` object that represents the new row.

With `Set s1_table_object_row = s1_table_list_object.ListRows.Add`, `s1_table_object_row` is the new row *returned* by `ListRows.Add`.

---

> [`ListRow.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrow.delete): Deletes the cells of the list row and shifts upward any remaining cells below the deleted row.

Note the difference - the first is [`ListRows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrows) and returns an object, the second is [`ListRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrow) (no `s`) and *doesn't return anything*. It can't return an object, because it deletes the object.

---

You have a reference to the new row: `s1_table_object_row`. So all you need to do is call `Delete` on that row.

```
s1_table_object_row.Delete
```

No `Set` or new variable, because `ListRow.Delete` doesn't return anything.

And there is no `ListRows.Delete` method, only `ListRow.Delete`.